# To get not exact match

Tags: excel, vba

i have below code working fine if cell value is exact same but i want vba to match the value before "_ " for eg. I want code to be work if i find "ABC" and Source data has contain "ABC_05" or "ABC_06" than it should match the data and process these value as well.

```
   ' Match
    Dim trg As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(sData)
        If foundMatchInVector(sData(i, 1), lData) Then
            Set trg = getCombinedRange(trg, srg.Cells(i))
        End If
    Next i
            
    ' Destination
    If Not trg Is Nothing Then
        Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
        ' This is a kind of a ridiculous use of "refColumn".
        Dim drg As Range: Set drg = refColumn(dws.Range(dFirst))
        If drg Is Nothing Then
            Set drg = dws.Range(dFirst).EntireRow
        Else
            Set drg = drg.Cells(drg.Cells.Count).Offset(1).EntireRow
        End If
        trg.EntireRow.Copy drg
        trg.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    
 

End Sub

' Assumptions:  'FirstCellRange' is a one-cell range e.g. 'Range("A1")'.
' Returns:      Either the range from 'FirstCellRange' to the bottom-most
'               non-empty cell in the column, or 'Nothing' if all cells
'               below 'FirstCellRange' (incl.) are empty.
Function refColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCellRange As Range) _
As Range
    With FirstCellRange
        Dim cel As Range
        Set cel = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If Not cel Is Nothing Then
            Set refColumn = .Resize(cel.Row - .Row + 1)
        End If
    End With
End Function

' Assumptions:  'rg' is a one-column range e.g. 'Range("A1")', 'Range("A1:A2")'.
' Returns:      A 2D one-based one-column array.
Function getColumn( _
    rg As Range) _
As Variant
    If rg.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        getColumn = rg.Value
    Else
        Dim OneElement As Variant: ReDim OneElement(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        OneElement(1, 1) = rg.Value
        getColumn = OneElement
    End If
End Function

' Assumptions:  'MatchValue' is a simple data type (not an object or an array).
'               'Vector' is a structure that 'Application.Match' can handle,
'               e.g. a 1D array, a one-column or one-row range or 2D array.
' Returns:      'True' or 'False' (boolean).
' Remarks:      Error values and blanks are ignored ('False').
Function foundMatchInVector( _
    ByVal MatchValue As Variant, _
    ByVal Vector As Variant) _
As Boolean
    If Not IsError(MatchValue) Then
        If Len(MatchValue) > 0 Then
            foundMatchInVector _
                = IsNumeric(Application.Match(MatchValue, Vector, 0))
        End If
    End If
End Function

' Assumptions:  'AddRange' is not 'Nothing' and it is in the same worksheet
'               as 'BuiltRange'.
' Returns:      A range (object).
Function getCombinedRange( _
        ByVal BuiltRange As Range, _
        ByVal AddRange As Range)
    If BuiltRange Is Nothing Then
        Set getCombinedRange = AddRange
    Else
        Set getCombinedRange = Union(BuiltRange, AddRange)
    End If
End Function
```

Currently macro is working fine if value is exact match but i have some data which contain extra charachter after "_XX" and

Comment: You posted a lot of irrelevant code... Please, try focusing only on the function, even code line, you need to adapt in order to behave as you tried explaining in words. We cannot waste our time looking in a lot of code which does not help at all in understanding of your problem;.

Comment: apologies, thanks for the your feedback, but i am new and learning it, i will take care of it for future post.

Comment: Nothing can stop you editing your question and sow us what you think is relevant. **I am trying to help you**! Otherwise, it is improbable that somebody will be patient enough and has more time to spent on understanding all the code, for only understanding a punctual problem. But, who knows? Maybe other people will do it... :)

Comment: need to amend this code Function foundMatchInVector( _
    ByVal MatchValue As Variant, _
    ByVal Vector As Variant) _
As Boolean
    If Not IsError(MatchValue) Then
        If Len(MatchValue) > 0 Then
            foundMatchInVector _
                = IsNumeric(Application.Match(MatchValue, Vector, 0))
        End If
    End If
End Function

Comment: Placing code in comments makes it hard to be understood. I would still suggest you to edit your question, let only the function in discussion and give us the relevant context. Now you are using 'xxx_yy' string and need to use 'xxx', or whatever you consider is necessary. But, at the first glance, `Match` function cannot search for partial part of a string. Also, at the first glance, I would suggest to use `Find`. But, I can think better if you will clean your question from unnecessary information, which does not increase our enthusiasm in helping you. I would say, on contrary... :)

Comment: And avoid placing code in the comment, please. Except a single code line... But, if you are the question issuer, you should edit it and make there the necessary clarifications.

Comment: This is the line of code you need to change `Application.Match(MatchValue, Vector, 0)` - just change it to your own bespoke function to search `vector` for `MatchValue` in the way you want. Loop through Vector and use `InStr` or `Replace` or something ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When presented with this kind of problem -- parsing a set of data on one or more Excel worksheets, and summarizing or pasting the results somewhere else -- I find it much simpler to treat the Excel worksheet as a database table, using ActiveX Data Objects.

Add a reference (**Tools** -> **References...**) to the latest version of **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects** (usually 6.0).

Then you could write code similar to the following:

```vb
Const filepath As String = "C:\path\to\excel\file.xlsx"
Const sheetname As String = "Sheet1"
Const fieldname As String = "Field1"

Dim connectionString As String
connectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & filepath & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"""

Dim sql As String
sql = _
    "SELECT * " & _
    "FROM [" & sheetname & "$] " & _
    "WHERE [" & fieldname & "] = 'ABC' OR [" & fieldname & "] LIKE 'ABC_%'"

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sql, connectionString

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ' fill the Range object with the top-left cell you want to paste the results to.
rng.CopyFromRecordset rs
```

You'll have to supply the following:

- the path to the Excel file
- the name of the worksheet
- the name of the field to search within
- the destination range, where you want to paste the results (`drg` in your code)

Note that the above code assumes your data has a header row. If your data doesn't have a header row, then write `HDR=No` in the connection string. The fields will be automatically named `F1`, `F2`, `F3` etc.